# Proving inapproximability for minimum cycle covering

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, approximation, np

Consider the problem of cycle covering: Given a graph G, we look for a set C of cycles such that all vertex of V(G) are in at least one cycle of C and the number of cycles in C is minimum.

My task is to show that this problem does not admit an absolute approximation, i.e., there cannot be an algorithm H such that for all instances I of the problem, H(I) <= OPT(I) + k, where OPT(I) is the optimal value for I and k is a number greater or equal to 1. The usual technique is to show that if this algorithm existed, we could solve in polinomial time some NP-hard problem.

Does anyone know which problem could be used for that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theory, not programming

Comment: well this is not the first time I post questions about theory here, and there are lot of similar ones in the related questions...

Comment: @user137227 Although I answered the question, I second your opinion that the question might be off-topic as it is theoretical and not programming-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is an algorithm `H` such that there is a positive integer `k` such that for every graph `G`, `H(G)<=OPT(G)+k` holds, where `OPT(G)` denotes the minimum number of cycles necessary to cover all nodes of `G` and the runtime of `H` is polynomially bounded in `n`, where `n` is the number of nodes of `G`.

Given any graph `G`, create a graph `G'` which consists out of `k+1` isomorphic copies of `G`; note that the number of nodes in `G'` is `(k+1)n`, which is polynomially bounded in `n`. The following two cases can occur:

1. If `G` contains a Hamiltonian cycle, then `OPT(G')=k+1` and `H(G')<=OPT(G')+k=k+1+k=2k+1`.
2. If `G` does not contain a Hamiltonian cycle, then `OPT(G')>=2k+2>2k+1` hence `H(G')>2k+1`.

In total, `H` can be used to decide in a runtime bound ponlynomially bounded in `n` whether `G` contains a Hamiltonian cycle; however, as the decision whether `G` has a Hamiltonian cycle is an `NP`-complete decision problem, this is impossible unless `P=NP` holds.

Note: This approach is called 'gap creation', as instances are transformed in such a way that there is a gap in the objective value of

1. optimal solutions of yes-instances;
2. suboptimal solutions of yes-instances and feasible solutions of no-instances.